# App crashes before Firebase data is loaded when going back 1 screen

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am experiencing a small issue in regards to my Firebase functionality when retrieving data and leaving the view controller before the data is actually loaded. I realized that if I press my back button in a controller BEFORE the actual data is loaded into the VC, I get a crash in my console which is `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''`. This only occurs if I try to exit out too quick in the case a user wants to go somewhere else before data is loaded otherwise every function works perfectly fine.

I have already removed the observers for two of my Firebase functions in viewDidDissapear which helps since you do not want to leave an observer open but this doesn't solve my crash issue. I also have a progress HUD that shows and dismisses once the data is loaded but to no success. Below is 1 of my Firebase functions that's retrieving data for example.

```
func retrieveMessages() {
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("locations").child(titleString)
        ref.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,String>
                let text = snapshotValue["message"]!
                let sender = snapshotValue["username"]!
                let img = snapshotValue["userImage"]!
                let upvote = snapshotValue["upvote"]!
                let timestamp = snapshotValue["timestamp"]!
                let message = ChatMessage()
                message.msgTimestamp = timestamp
                message.messageBody = text
                message.sender = sender
                message.chatImageURL = img
                let upvoteInt = Int(upvote)
                message.upvoteString = upvoteInt!
                self.chatMessageArray.append(message)
                self.chatTable.reloadData()
                self.chatRoomScrollToBottom(animated: true)
                        }
                    }
                }
```

My next hypothesis would be to disable the back button until the data is fully loaded? That would solve this issue but I am wondering if there is a way to halt this function or any FB function that I fire if I press my back button immediately? Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Can you specify on which line it gets crash? `Firebase retrieve path was invalid.`

Comment: I'm not sure. I get a SIGABRT error and this is what shows in the console `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''` It did not crash on any specific line so I'm not sure which of the Firebase functions it was. Is there a way to find the exact line with this specific error?

Comment: Are you sure that `titleString` is a non-empty String?

Comment: Yes 100% positive. Everything loads exceptionally well. My issue is if I back out too quickly when I press my back button. This interrupts the flow of how Firebase loads data when its not fully retrieved yet. I'm trying to figure out how to work around that.

Comment: have you set `titleString` anywhere twice?

Comment: I have but I don’t see how that interferes with the way I get this error. I use that variable to retrieve similar data elsewhere. Again, my issue isn’t this function I posted but the fact that ANY of my Firebase functions I have will crash if you leave a view controller before data is shown.

Comment: @PaulPurser `leave a view controller before data is shown` - that's not the issue, if you remove your observers correctly before leaving that controller or update any global variable correctly. So add your code snippet where you are removing observers and where you reset the `titleString` for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try running the following, and comment the output:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class FirebaseTableViewController: UITableViewController  {

    lazy var ref: DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference()
    var chatMessageArray: Array<ChatMessage> = []
    var messageRef: DatabaseReference!
    var titleString = ""    //TODO: Update this
    var chatTable: UITableView = UITableView() //TODO: Update this



    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(titleString) // TODO: Check that it dose not contain: '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''
        messageRef = ref.child("locations").child(titleString)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        chatMessageArray.removeAll()
        messageRef.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            self.createMessage(snapshot:snapshot)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        // removeAllObservers: Removes all observers at the current reference, but does not remove any observers at child references
        messageRef.removeAllObservers()
    }

    func chatRoomScrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {

    }

    func createMessage(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        guard let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,String> else {
            print("Error with snapshotValue")
            return
        }
        guard let text = snapshotValue["message"],
            let sender = snapshotValue["username"],
            let img = snapshotValue["userImage"],
            let upvote = snapshotValue["upvote"],
            let timestamp = snapshotValue["timestamp"] else {
                print("Error with snapshotValue[''] values")
                return
        }
        let message = ChatMessage()
        message.msgTimestamp = timestamp
        message.messageBody = text
        message.sender = sender
        message.chatImageURL = img
        guard let upvoteInt = Int(upvote) else {
            print ("Error with pvoteInt")
            return
        }
        message.upvoteString = String(upvoteInt)
        self.chatMessageArray.append(message)
        self.chatTable.reloadData()
        self.chatRoomScrollToBottom(animated: true)
    }

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sir thank you so much. I did this also for my second observer in this view controller. I remove them exactly like how you did. I want to show a progress HUD so the user can also wait while the data loads. I put ``SVProgressHUD().show`` right in the beginning of ``createMessage`` and then dismiss it at the end. Is this a good area to place that? So when the user is waiting for data to load, then can see something is loading?